# How do I store files greater than 5GB in size on S3 using ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have an application hosted on Heroku.  Part of it's job is to store / serve up files of varying sizes, zipped up in bundles.  (We're planning to phase out the bundling process at a later date, but that's going to be a major revamp of consuming software)

The 5GB limit on file uploads to S3 (caused by S3 requiring multiple part uploads) is becoming increasingly untenable for our use-case.  In fact, it's become an outright pain and outright unacceptable to the business model.

Rails 6.1 is supposed to fix this, but we can't wait for it to come out, especially since there isn't an ETA on it yet.  I tried using the alpha version off master, and got hit with an error about not being able to load coffee script (which is weird since I don't *use* coffeescript).

I'm now trying to find other viable alternatives that will allow our application to store files of 5GB or larger.  I'm experimenting with compressing the files, but that isn't a long-term solution either.

Comment: Unfortunately [Rails UJS](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2f6456cbe1da73c13b37e23720caa8716df85e78/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) is still written in Coffescript.

Comment: @max thank you.  Your comment just made me challenge an unstated assumption: rails bundles coffeescript with itself, right?  Answer: not anymore!